# Most efficient way to store values in unordered_set using disk space in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, disk, unordered-set

I am writing a program to remove duplicate lines in a file, and I use unordered_set to store line hashes (specifically, [this library](https://github.com/martinus/robin-hood-hashing), since it is several times faster than the standard `std::unordered_set`)

Since sometimes the computer's RAM is not enough to process all the lines in the file, it is necessary to store some of the hashes in a container on disk (for example, something like **stxxl**). However, there is no unordered_set in stxxl, and besides, it does not seem to be the most optimal in terms of speed and memory consumption.

Please tell me (if possible, with code examples) - what is better to use in this case?

Comment: I'd approach this problem with merge sort + consecutive duplicate removal, neither of which require loading the whole file into memory, not hashing.

Comment: you need a key-value database. ndbm for example

Comment: "*sometimes the computer's RAM is not enough to process all the lines in the file*" - Really? How large are the files you are hashing? Even the largest text files likely won't take up much memory. And hashes are small, so a container of hashes won't take up much memory, either. But even so, you can certainly hash an entire file without actually having the whole file loaded in memory at one time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The answer is in my previous thread. Files can be over 100 gigabytes in size

Comment: @yurikilochek It's too slow. More precisely, so slowly that we will all die faster than one file per couple of hundred gigabytes is sorted

Comment: There seems to be a `stxxl::unordered_map`, so you can try `std::unordered_set<T>` -> `stxxl::unordered_map<T, std::monostate>`

Comment: What if you remove the duplicates in multiple passes? As a simple example, first remove duplicate lines that start with "A", then remove duplicate lines that start with "B", and so on. That way you never load the entire file at once. You'd need to figure out a way to roughly evenly split the file though, in case 99% of the lines start with an "A" or something.

Comment: What fraction of lines are duplicates? How long are the typical lines? Does the output have to be in the order first seen in the input? (Where I'm going with this is: Can you get away with cryptographically hashing lines and so be able to avoid storing the original line; instead storing a secure hash of the original line.)

Comment: @Ben I already store only hash, not line

Comment: @Artyer stxxl not working on MSVC 2022, and project on gihub not maintained. Is there any alternatives?